# C++ контейнеры map и set

Tags: c++

Расжуйте пожалуйста эти строки:

```
set<string> set1;
map<set<string>, int> map1;
```

Новичок и не могу понять, map - это [ключ,значение], но тут мы в map в ключ ничего не кладем, а добавляем слова в set1. И после добавления слов можем через map1 к ним обращаться.
Например:

```
`string lol;
 int k;
 cin >> lol;
 set1.insert(lol);
 map1[set1] = k;`
```

И как их выводить после.
Выводит значение:

```
cout << map1[set1] << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

*"но тут мы в map в ключ ничего не кладем"* - вот тут вы ошибаетесь, оператор [] в map как раз создает новую пару ключ-дефолтное значение, если такого ключа еще не было.

Comment: В set добавляем слова, задаем число k, для ключа;
map1[set1] = k;
Для какого ключа тогда задается значение k?

Comment: @Piter для указанного в аргументе оператора [], для ключа, скопированного из `set1`, то бишь

Comment: Спасибо, вроде потихоньку начинаю понимать

Comment: @Piter `map` в этом плане работает необычно, у других контейнеров, прежде всего у `vector` и простых массивов для вызова оператора [] надо сначала обязательно добавить элемент, а сам оператор этого делать не будет.

Comment: И в данном map не получается вывести ключ-значение как бы это было с map<string,int>.

Comment: @Piter почему не получается?

Comment: @Piter: Что значит "не получается"? Все получается.